# How can I get the value back from a templated parent class without knowing the underlying type?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Given these definitions and some code along these lines for illustration purposes:

```
class Child
{
    private:
    std::string name;

    public:
    Child(const std::string & name) name(name)
    { }
}

template<typename T>
class Parent : public Child
{
    private:
    T data;

    public Parent(const std::string & name, const T & data) : Child(name), data(data)
    { }

    inline GetData() const
    {
        return this->data;
    }
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Child>> values;
values.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Parent<int>>("value a", 4));
values.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Parent<std::string>>("value b", "test"));

for (const auto & v : values)
{
    // I want to access the int and string here!
}
```

How would I determine the type used in the parent class from the base class here?

The concrete scenario I am working with is actually that I have a bunch of `SqlParameterBase` classes which contain information about SQL parameters for stored procedures and a `SqlParameter<T>` template that is supposed to be contained in a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SqlParameterBase>>` and passed into a class that represents a stored procedure configuration, so that it can be called.

But the fundamental problem here is that I need access to the underlying data and I wanted to avoid defining a `void *` in the base class to contain a pointer to the data. I'd prefer it to be as type safe as possible.

I'm open to alternative designs or approaches to solving this problem as well, so please feel free to suggest something entirely different if you feel it's better.

Comment: You'll need to `dynamic_cast`, but what you really want is a variant type.

Comment: Yeah I know I'll need to do a dynamic cast to the parent type. The thing is, I can't determine which type to cast to without testing every single type in a hard coded fashion. In the end, I basically need to be able to determine the size of whatever the data is, like the number of elements in the vector or the length of a string; those member functions change based on the type. I thought about a template and just assuming T::size exists, but it may be risky if the function's behavior is defined differently between types.

Comment: If you need to determine a "size" of the data, how about adding `virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;` to `Child`?

Comment: @aschepler missed your comment before posting my comment on an answer below. This seems like the easiest approach but the downside is that I have to make classes for *each* data type I want to support.

Comment: May I ask what exactly you plan to do with the data in that for? And why this can't be done under the responsibility of parent? I'm asking mostly of curiosity.

Comment: @Aziuth In my real code, I am making an abstraction for Microsoft's SQL connectivity client and want to store a vector of parameters. Each of the parameters can have different data types (both native and SQL types) and many native types can map to one kind of SQL type (vector, array, string, can map to varchar). I am going to take a pointer to it and pass it to the function Microsoft has exposed to bind parameters to a parameterized SQL statement. This requires a pointer to the data (void *) and a size of the data (numbers of chars, length of binary data, etc). This reduces complexity overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want Child promise functionality (returning typed data) that only exists in derived types. Under inheritance, this is abstract functionality. So a set of speculative virtual accessors. upcasts aren't really required here.

I would say. If you don't want Child to promise what it returns, just that it returns *something* then it seems like your interface is too broad, you are putting the interface in the code that consumes the interface instead, say with speculative casts etc.

Either a set of Child's can be interfaced with though the interface defined in Child or they have some special functionality only available in Derived and must be spoken to that way.

As a wee addendum, you might consider a `std::vector<std::variant<type1, type2, ...>>` instead of completely erroding the type information in the container? std::variant is C++17 ofc so may not be suitable, but there are 3rd party implementations - boost variant etc.

Comment: You said abstract functionality and it made me think. Would it be an appropriate design to have a `virtual size_t GetSize() = 0` in my parent class and then implement it in numerous child classes that specialize to the supported backing data? For example, I'd have a `StringChild` and a `IntChild` and each would implement their own way of getting their data and data size. I'd then switch inside my loop and use an enum to keep track of the data type and then dynamically cast it when I need to get the data. Seems like a lot of code, but it makes my interface far narrower.

Comment: After some reading and messing around, `std::variant` fits my needs quite well actually. I've reduced my functionality to a set of supported types for each of the SQL types and just *attempt* conversions of the few supported data types based on the expected SQL type for the parameter in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this program (for the question: *How would I determine the type used in the parent class from the base class here?*):

The output prints the types..
But some more work is needed to look better

```
value a of type:i
value b of type:NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

Here "i" means integer in the first line.

The second one has "basic_string" in it. But some junk around it.

I am posting this because, it may trigger better ideas.

Added comments for the code modified.

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

//CREATED ANOTHER VARIABLE AND FUNCTION FOR TYPENAME.
//MODIFIED CONSTRUCTOR ACCORDINGLY.
class Child 
{
    private:
    std::string name;
    std::string tyName;

    public:
    Child(const std::string & name,const std::string &tyname):name(name), tyName (tyname)
    { }

    std::string  getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    std::string  getTypeName()
    {
        return tyName;
    }
};

//MODIFIED CONSTRUCTOR TO PASS THE TYPENAME TO PARENT CLASS.
template<typename T>
class Parent : public Child
{
     private:
     T data;

     public:
     Parent(const std::string & name, const T & data) : Child(name,typeid(data).name()), data(data) 
     { }

     inline T GetData() const
     {
           return this->data;
       }
};



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Child>> values;
    values.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Parent<int>>("value a", 4));
    values.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Parent<std::string>>("value b", "test"));


    //GET THE POINTER OF YOUR BASE CLASS.
    //PRINT THE TYPE NAME.
    for (const auto & v : values)
    {
        Child *p = dynamic_cast<Child*>(v.get());
        std::cout<<p->getName()<<" of type:"<<p->getTypeName()<<std::endl;        
    }

    return 0;
}
```